# System.assertequal fails but debug log shows id

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a test class that keeps failing on the last assert.  The debug shows the newly created system record so not sure why it keeps failing.

```
 Location_c location = new Location_c(
        Name = 'Location'
    );
    insert location;
    
    List<Location_c> location1 = [
        SELECT Id,name
        FROM Location__c
    ];

    System.assertEquals( 1, location1.size(), 'location was found was found' );

    System__c s = new System__c(
        Name = 'Test System',
        Drill_Price__c = 0
    );
    insert s;

    List<System__c> locsytem = [
        SELECT Id,name,Drill_Price__c
        FROM System__c
    ];

    System.assertEquals( 1, locsytem.size(), 'System was found' );

    system.debug('System Id ' + s.Id);
    List<Location__c> location2 = [
        SELECT Id,system__c 
        FROM Location__c where system__c =: s.Id
    ];
   
    System.assertEquals( 1, location2 .size(), 'Location with system was found' );
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that when you inserted `Location__c`, it did not have a value for field `System__c`

You will need to insert `System__c` first and then include its Id in the setup of `Location__c`

Comment: Perfect.  thanks